# Django - Configure multidomain with django.sites

Tags: python, django, middleware

I've created a project with some apps in Django:

```
Project
--> App1
--> App2
--> App3
```

I've a domain for every app:

> domain1.ex domain2.ex domain3.ex

I want that, visiting domain1.ex, the App1 will be loaded. I've readed the [Middleware Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/middleware/) without results. How I hould I do?

Comment: What do you mean the app will be loaded? Do you want to route to that app only? It would be easier with a more concrete example of what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a settings file for each domain where you list the apps that should be loaded and set `SITE_ID` to a different number for each file (if you are using the sites framework). Then create a wsgi.py file for each domain where you set the environment variable to the corresponding settings file as `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`.

You have to configure your web server to load the correct wsgi file for your domain.

Comment: Thanks, it was the explanation I was looking for!